# mxnet (mshadow) getting the shape of a tensor

Tags: shapes, mxnet, tensor

I'm a newbie in mshadow, I can not understand why I got those outpus from the following code snippet:

```
TensorContainer<cpu, 2> lhs(Shape2(2, 3));
lhs = 1.0;
printf("%u %u\n", lhs.size(0), lhs.size(1));
printf("%u %u\n", lhs[0].shape_[0], lhs[0].shape_[1]);
printf("%u %u\n", lhs[0].size(0), lhs[0].size(1));
```

The output is:

```
2 3
3 4
3 3
```

Why are the second and third outputs those numbers? Because `lhs[0]` is one-dimensional, I think they should be exactly the same, i.e. `3 0`. Could anyone tell me where I was wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Tensor lhs[0] is one dimensional, but to answer you question first let me show what is going on under the hood. TensorContainer does not override the [] operator, instead it uses the one from the parent (which is Tensor), more precisely the [following one](https://github.com/dmlc/mshadow/blob/223b45a5cedf126a50b6c8ca4c82ede8c81874e0/mshadow/tensor.h#L391) is called:

```
  MSHADOW_XINLINE Tensor<Device, kSubdim, DType> operator[](index_t idx) const {
    return Tensor<Device, kSubdim, DType>(dptr_ + this->MemSize<1>() * idx,
                                          shape_.SubShape(), stride_, stream_);
  }
```

As can be seen it creates a new Tensor on a stack. And while for the most of the cases it will create generic [N-dimensional Tensor](https://github.com/dmlc/mshadow/blob/492a0037c6ad8c93c63053e610d8b1d4a8f25dfe/mshadow/tensor.h#L400), here for the 1-dimensional case it will create a special [1-dimensional Tensor](https://github.com/dmlc/mshadow/blob/223b45a5cedf126a50b6c8ca4c82ede8c81874e0/mshadow/tensor.h#L432).

Now ,when we have established what exactly is returned by the operator [], let's look on the fields of that class:

```
  DType *dptr_;
  Shape<1> shape_;
  index_t stride_;
```

As can be seen the shape_ here has only 1 dimension! so there is no shape_[1](https://github.com/dmlc/mshadow/blob/223b45a5cedf126a50b6c8ca4c82ede8c81874e0/mshadow/tensor.h#L391), instead by calling shape_[1](https://github.com/dmlc/mshadow/blob/223b45a5cedf126a50b6c8ca4c82ede8c81874e0/mshadow/tensor.h#L391) it will return stride_(or part of it). Here is the modification to the Tensor constructor that you can try to run and see what is actually going on there:

```
  MSHADOW_XINLINE Tensor(DType *dptr, Shape<1> shape,
                         index_t stride, Stream<Device> *stream)
      : dptr_(dptr), shape_(shape), stride_(stride), stream_(stream) {
     std::cout << "shape[0]: " << shape[0] << std::endl; // 3
     std::cout << "shape[1]: " << shape[1] << std::endl; // 0, as expected
     std::cout << "_shape[0]: " << shape_[0] << std::endl; // 3, as expected
     std::cout << "_shape[1]: " << shape_[1] << std::endl; // garbage (4)
     std::cout << "address of _shape[1]: " << &(shape_[1]) << std::endl;
     std::cout << "address of stride: " << &(stride_) << std::endl;
  }
```

and the output:

```
shape[0]: 3
shape[1]: 0
_shape[0]: 3
_shape[1]: 4
address of _shape[1]: 0x7fffa28ec44c
address of stride: 0x7fffa28ec44c
```

_shape[1](https://github.com/dmlc/mshadow/blob/223b45a5cedf126a50b6c8ca4c82ede8c81874e0/mshadow/tensor.h#L391) and stride have both the same address (0x7fffa28ec44c).

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ROBOTAI if you think this is the correct answer, may I ask you to mark it as correct?